# Access to numerically indexed array in wpdb Class and undefined offset

Tags: wpdb, array

the following database call

```
$einzel = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT t.id, DATE_FORMAT(t.datum, '%d.%m.%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(t.datum2, '%d.%m.%Y'), t.ueberschrift, t.uhrzeit, t.termintext, t.veranstaltungsort, t.ort, v.name, v.id, ku.name, ku.mail
                                FROM veranstaltungen t, kalender_user ku, vereine v
                                WHERE t.id = '".$id."'
                                AND t.referfasser = ku.id
                                AND ku.verein_id = v.id", ARRAY_N );
```

delivers in PHPMyAdmin
[image: Database Request]

In my php-scrpit

```
echo $einzel[0]."<br />";
echo $einzel[1]."<br />";
echo $einzel[2]."<br />";
echo $einzel[3]."<br />";
echo $einzel[4]."<br />";
echo $einzel[5]."<br />";
echo $einzel[6]."<br />";
echo $einzel[7]."<br />";
echo $einzel[8]."<br />";
echo $einzel[9]."<br />";
echo $einzel[10]."<br />";
echo $einzel[11]."<br />";
```

delivers these

```
144
21.05.2020
00.00.0000
Zugtag der Königsgilde Voitze
ab 10.00 Uhr 

Schützenhaus Voitze, Salzwedeler Straße
Voitze
Gaede,Joerg
joerg.gaede@t-online.de

Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in ...veranstaltungen.php on line 192
Notice: Undefined offset: 11 in ...veranstaltungen.php on line 193
```

Why don't i have access to numbers 10 and 11 here?
Greeting Bernd

Comment: Can you try to print the $einzel variable and paste the output here?

Answer (score 0):

var_dump($einzel);

```
array(10) { [0]=> string(3) "144" [1]=> string(10) "21.05.2020" [2]=> string(10) "00.00.0000" [3]=> string(30) "Zugtag der Königsgilde Voitze" [4]=> string(14) " ab 10.00 Uhr " [5]=> string(0) "" [6]=> string(41) "Schützenhaus Voitze, Salzwedeler Straße" [7]=> string(6) "Voitze" [8]=> string(11) "Gaede,Joerg" [9]=> string(23) "joerg.gaede@t-online.de" }
```

There are two same column names: 'id' and 'name'.
I worked around the problem and changed one column name from 'name' into 'verein' and take away one 'id' (only need one).
So it works for me, but the question remains, why does it work with PHPMyAdmin, or not with wpdb.